# how to change the image inside the li a img when hover the entire li using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the image inside the anchors inside the list item (li a img) using this simple jquery script but only change the image if the mouse is hover it, but i need to change the image if hover the entire li.

```
$(".overview li a img").hover(
    function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on"); },
    function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off"); }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your selector to target the `li`, then within the handlers find the `img` children and modify their sources:

```
$(".overview li").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find("img")[0].src = $(this).find("img")[0].src.replace("_off", "_on");
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("img")[0].src = $(this).find("img")[0].src.replace("_on", "_off");
    });    
});
```

If you like, you can squeeze that behaviour into a single function argument to `.hover` (it is a bit less readable though):

```
$(".overview li").hover(function () {
    var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
    img.src = (img.src.indexOf("_off") > -1) ? 
        img.src.replace("_off", "_on") : img.src.replace("_on", "_off");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about using [CSS](http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp), along with [sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) to achieve this effect?

This will give you exactly what you want, without having to resort to javascript and without a slight delay on hover while the image loads for the first time